# Listen-only (stealth) CDP on IOS

Tags: cisco, security, cisco-ios, cisco-commands, cdp

I would like to put my router in a listen-only mode for CDP i.e. it should allow CDP packets to only arrive while not advertising so that I can glimpse into physical topology while remaining hidden to other nodes.

Currently neither I am unable to filter CDP packets per interface in egress direction with an access list as CDP runs on data link layer AFAIK nor suppress advertisements with a specific CDP command syntax.

Comment: CDP has no native ability to do this. EDITED to add: I can't think of a way to do this unless you're doing frame inspection inbetween this device and others.

Comment: @dprogrammer, what platform(s) and IOS(s) do you need to do this on?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't do this on router level, if your device are Cisco switch you can apply mac access-list which will drop outgoing CDP packets, and because CDP use ARPA code (EtherType) 0x2000, mac access-list will contain: 
access-list 10 deny 0x2000

Comment: Wow, that's interesting! Is this used exclusively for CDP, or do I risk blocking something else? Where did you come across this info?

Comment: no this will block CDP only , you can block any Datalink protocol using mac acl and you can find more info here :http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus1000/sw/4_0/security/configuration/guide/n1000v_security/security_9mac_acls.html

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is likely to disable CDP on WAN ports and enable it on your management interfaces, otherwise there is not a listen only equivalent up to ios 15 on routers that I'm aware of.
See the following for step by step:

```
Router(config)# no cdp run
Router(config)# end
Router# show cdp
% CDP is not enabled
Router# configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)# interface TenGigabitEthernet4/1
Router(config-if)# cdp enable
```

The above is sourced from: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/optical/cpt/r9_5/command/reference/cpt95_cr/cpt95_cr_chapter_01101.pdf

Comment: I disagree on that. `CDP is enabled by default at the global level and on each supported interface to send or receive CDP information. If CDP is disabled globally, you cannot enable it on each interface using the cdpenable interface configuration mode command.`

Comment: Hmm I recall that being the case on older IOS. However that list of commands is directly from a Cisco command reference. I have a few older routers at home I can test with at a later date but unfortunately my work consists entirely of Mikrotik routers these days...

Comment: This is still actual. If you will globally disable CDP then you will not be able to turn it on for specific interface: `% Cannot enable CDP on this interface, since CDP is not running`